# Close sidebar by default

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I work with a Bootstrap template, everything is better so far or I wanted to make "Close" the default sidebar. I tried a few tips on the net without change. My preoccupation is how to make the sidebar hidden when loading the page? here the code I'm trying to adapt:

/*!

- Start Bootstrap - SB Admin 2 v4.0.7 (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2)
- Copyright 2013-2019 Start Bootstrap
- Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/blob/master/LICENSE)
  */

```
!function(t){
  "use strict";
   $("#sidebarToggle, #sidebarToggleTop").on("click",function(o){
    $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-toggled"),$(".sidebar").toggleClass("toggled"),$(".sidebar").hasClass("toggled")&&
    t(".sidebar .collapse").collapse("hide")}),t(window).resize(function(){t(window).width()<768&&t(".sidebar .collapse").collapse("hide")
    }),
t("body.fixed-nav .sidebar").on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel",function(o){if(768<t(window).width()){
    var e=o.originalEvent,l=e.wheelDelta||-e.detail;this.scrollTop+=30*(l<0?1:-1),o.preventDefault()
    }
    }),t(document).on("scroll",function(){
        100<t(this).scrollTop()?t(".scroll-to-top").fadeIn():t(".scroll-to-top").fadeOut()
        }
        ),t(document).on("click","a.scroll-to-top",function(o){
            var e=t(this);t("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:t(e.attr("href")).offset().top},1e3,"easeInOutExpo"),o.preventDefault()
}
)}(jQuery);
```

I have a Bootstrap template that contains a sidebar. The sidebar is open by default, but I want it to be closed by default, so when the user loads the website, he has to click the button before get the sidebar open.

[image]
[image]

Comment: May be incomplete question. Please edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but as the answer doesn't seem to be here I thought I would add it.

Add the class "sidebar-toggled" to the < body /> and add the class "toggled" to the < ul id="accordianSidebar" />

```
<body id="page-top" class="sidebar-toggled">
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-dark sidebar sidebar-dark accordion toggled" id="accordionSidebar">
```

That will start the sidebar as shrunk but keep the toggle features as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can control your sidebar with direct Javascript. I also faced problem with jQuery.

```
// Sidebar Controlling Javascript Code
// #CategorySidebarID is the id of sidebar

document.getElementById("CategorySidebarID").style.display = "none";

// Call this function from which button it will be open.
function sidebar_open() {
  document.getElementById("CategorySidebarID").style.display = "block";
}

// Same as open, close button.
function sidebar_close() {
  document.getElementById("CategorySidebarID").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help   I tried the code but it made the sidebar disappear completely. My wish is that it is closed by default and that all times the user can click a button to open it

Comment: Did you call the functions?

Comment: @Mr. Perfectionist: Great Answer

Comment: @AsiyaFatima Exactly.